# Get dates by month in a range using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am learning how to use LINQ properly I've been struggling to get the dates sorted by month. Here is the approach I am trying to use.

```
var attentdanceList = from attent in attentdance
                      orderby attent.UpdatedOn descending
                      where attent.Present is (false)
                      select new AttentdanceResponse
                      {
                        Id = attent.RowKey,
                        SchoolId = attent.PartitionKey,
                        StudentId = attent.StudentId,
                        ClassRoomId = attent.ClassRoomId,
                        TeacherId = attent.TeacherId,
                        Latitude = attent.Latitude,
                        Longitude = attent.Longitude,
                        Present = attent.Present,
                        Timestamp = (DateTime)attent.UpdatedOn
                      };
```

Output:

[image: output]

Expected output: to get data from the current month.

Comment: What is your expected output? Ordering by date is effectively sorting by month (and year and day and time). And what relevance does your WHERE criteria have?

Comment: UpdatedOn isn't a DateTime already?

Comment: Hi, @Ralf I've updated the question and added the full attendance object view. Yes UpdatedOn is DateTime

Comment: Then the sorting looks ok to me. Your comparison looks wrong. When its a Datetime you shouldn't compare with a string.  So rather `where !attent.Present && attent.UpdatedOn.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && attent.UpdatedOn.Year == DateTime.Today.Year` . But thats just guessing as title, text and code of your question still contradicts itself.

Comment: After your edit it seems that i guessed correctly, Can you have attendance data from the future or will your timestamp always be in the past?

Comment: @Ralf yes it'll always be in the past.

Comment: In that case `where !attent.Present && attent.UpdatedOn >= new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);` might be a bit simpler. Writing an Extension method for "beginning of month" might make it even simpler/more beautiful.